# Open python script with python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I need help because I want to open a python script with a python script so could someone please out?

Code:

```
import subprocess


python_script = ("C://Users//Jay//Documents//Python Programs//HelloWorld.py")

subprocess.call(" python python_script 1", shell=True)
```

Error:
python: can't open file 'python_script': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: don't use python_script literally in your command line

Comment: To be clearer, you can fix this with `subprocess.call(f"python {python_script} 1", shell=True)` if you have a newer version of Python. Python won't interpret `python_script` in a string as a variable simply because a variable exists with that name.

Comment: Why do you want two Python processes? Why not make a imports from one Python file to another?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
subprocess.call(" python "+python_script+" 1", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should paste a variable into your string, not just another string.

For this purpose you can use several techniques:

**f-strings**

```py
subprocess.call(f"python {python_script} 1", shell=True)
```

**simple concatenation**

```py
subprocess.call("python " + python_script" + " 1", shell=True)
```

**`format` method**

```py
subprocess.call("python {} 1".format(python_script), shell=True)
```